# What's the naming convention for ngettext short name?

Tags: application-development, python, internationalization, gettext

gettext.gettext is imported as `_`:

```
from gettext import gettext as _
```

It's some naming convention, right? What's the equivalent for gettext.ngettext? `__`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen `P_` (I assume the letter P stands for plural) used sometimes, but it seems there is not a general agreement or a defined standard for a shortcut to plural strings for translations in gettext.

Generally these shortcuts or macros are used in C and come from GLib, so they are not standard shortcuts from Gettext, but they've become a de facto standard for programs that use GLib. They are generally defined in the `/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gi18n.h` file, and explained in detail on the [Internationalization API docs for GLib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-I18N.html).

There are definitions for `_` (gettext), `Q_` (context), `C_` (context), `N_` (mark for translation only) and `NC_` (mark for translation only, with context), but no `P_`

In any case, in Python you'll need to define the shortcuts yourself, but it'd be goot to stick to the same naming convention, for consistency's sake.

However, I seem to remember intltool does not recognize the `P_` shortcut by default, so since ngettext is not used as often as gettext, you might want to just use the actual name of the function and not a shortcut.

If you still want to use a shortcut, and it is not supported by intltool, you'll need to tell intltool to use it, IIRC through the `XGETTEXT` variable or through the use of a `Makevars` file.

Comment: indeed, these strings were missing from the `.pot` file

Comment: However, I like the idea to use `__` (double underscore) for this...